# What verb is used for the way that dogs walk?

Tags: verbos, animales

What kind of verbs are used, for the different ways a dog walks?

For instance, in the case of a **horse**, it could be **trotar** or **galopar**.

What possibilities exist for a dog?

Comment: Are there words for it in English?

Comment: @Rodrigo - The only one I can think of is *lope* (seems to work even better for wolves).  I guess a wolf could also slink into the shadows.  A dog who feels unwanted might skulk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific verb, you can go either with *andar* or *caminar*, even *correr* or *trotar* if it is running

Answer (score 0):

No, for dogs there is not an specific word, you can just use "caminar" that applies to horses too, "galopar" it's just a specific style.